# what is a memory warning, how do we respond to it

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iPhone development. Here in don't know what memory management is, and how we respond to it.

Can any one please help for my problem?

Comment: It is not clear whether you’re asking about iOS memory warnings (in which the OS tells the application that it’s using too much memory) or memory management (how to allocate and dispose objects). At any rate, Stack Overflow already has questions and answers for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is your friend. The Memory Usage Performance Guidelines doc has a section on [Responding to Low-Memory Warnings in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001881-SW1). Similarly the iOS Application Programming Guide has a section on [Observing Low-Memory Warnings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW6).